# Fixing obsolete warning of RestResponseCookie

Tags: c#, api, cookies, restsharp

I have a project that is using RestResponseCookie, it is showing me a warning that RestResponseCookie is obsolete, how can I solve the warning?

Here is the exact warning

```
Warning CS0618  'RestResponseCookie' is obsolete: 'We will use HttpCookie in the response as well in the next major version'
```

Comment: The only way to fix the warning is not to use obsolete property/method anymore. change all places where you use 'RestResponseCookie' with a new alternative 'HttpCookie'

Comment: OK I'll try that, thank you

Comment: It is a warning message, you can instruct the compiler to ignore it. We try to give you an idea of the upcoming breaking change, that's all.

Comment: The only problem with that is that in May 2021, visual studio says HttpCookie is deprecated.